# How do we prove $\lim\inf s_n\le\lim\inf\sigma_n$ in the following case?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, proof-explanation, limsup-and-liminf

Let $s_n$ be a sequence of nonnegative numbers, and for each $n$ define $\sigma_n=\frac1n (s_1+s_2+...+s_n)$, how do we prove  $\lim\inf s_n\le\lim\inf\sigma_n$?

I was told two ways could be achieved:

$1.$ Suppose we have proved $\lim\sup \sigma_n\le\lim\sup s_n$, then we can do a little trick to prove the $\lim\inf$ version. My thought is that if we can somehow make $\lim\sup -\sigma_n\le\lim\sup -s_n$, then we can do $\lim\inf\sigma_n=-\lim\sup -\sigma_n\ge-\lim\sup -s_n=\lim\inf s_n$, but the problem is how do we make $\lim\sup -\sigma_n\le\lim\sup -s_n$.

$2.$ Directly prove it. My thought is that we can pick a $N$, $n>N\implies$ $\sigma_n=\frac1n (s_1+s_2+...+s_n)\ge \min\{s_1, ...,s_n\}\ge\inf s_n$. Since $\inf s_n$ is lower bound for $\sigma_n$, $\inf s_n\le\inf\sigma_n$, then taking the limit, we get $\lim\inf s_n\le\lim\inf\sigma_n$. But I felt taking limit part is not quite logical to me.

Could someone help?

Comment: For approach 2, you have envisioned the definition of liminf wrongly.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, let $k\geq n$ be arbitrary. Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sigma_{k}&=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^{k}s_{i}\\
&=\frac{1}{k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{k}s_{i}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{k}\left(\sigma_{n}+\sum_{i=n+1}^{k}s_{i}\right)\\
&\geq\frac{1}{k}\left(\sigma_{n}+(k-n-1)\inf_{i\geq n+1}s_{i} \right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Since this holds for all $k\geq n$ and using the fact that $\inf(a_{n}+b_{n})\geq\inf(a_{n})+\inf(b_{n})$, it follows that
$$
\inf_{k\geq n}\sigma_{k}\geq\inf_{k\geq n}\frac{\sigma_{n}}{k}+\inf_{k\geq n}\frac{k-n-1}{k}\inf_{i\geq n}s_{i}.
$$

Taking $n\to\infty$ gives
$$
\liminf\sigma_{n}\geq\liminf s_{n}.
$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $k-(n+1)+1$ instead of $k-(n+1)$, since there are $k-(n+1)+1$ terms. Also, in the last step, how does $n\to \infty$ gives the final result?

Answer (score 2):

Fix a $k\leq n$,

$\sigma_n=\frac 1 n \sum _1 ^{k-1} s_i + \frac 1 n \sum _k ^n s_i$

$\geq\frac 1 n \sum _1 ^{k-1} s_i + \min \{s_k,s_{k+1},..s_n \}$

$\geq\frac 1 n \sum _1 ^{k-1} s_i + \inf_{i\geq k} s_i$

Note that this holds for all $n\geq k$. For all finite $k$,

$\inf_{j\geq n} \sigma_j\geq \frac 1 n \sum _1 ^{k-1} s_i + \inf_{i\geq k} s_i$

Now we first take the limit w.r.t $n$ on both sides, and note that for all finite $k$,

$\liminf \sigma_j\geq \inf_{i\geq k} s_i$

Now, we take limit w.r.t $k$ on both sides, to get

$\liminf \sigma_n\geq \liminf s_n$

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct and you have to work a little bit harder.

We can write $\liminf _n s_n = \sup _{k}\inf_{n\geq k} s_n $.

We now fix $k$, and denote $  S_n= \sum _{i=1}^{n}s_n      $

So, 
\begin{align}
  \sigma _n&= \frac{   S_{k-1}   }{n}  +  \frac{ S_n-  S_{k-1}   }{n}\\
&\geq \frac{   S_{k-1}   }{n}  +  \frac{ (n-k)\min_{n\geq i\geq k}s_i   }{n}\\
&\geq \frac{   S_{k-1}   }{n}  +  \frac{ (n-k)\inf_{ i\geq k}s_i   }{n}
\end{align}
Taking $\liminf_n$ in both sides we obtain (notice that the limit of the RHS exists),
$$\liminf _n \sigma_n \geq \inf_{i\geq k}s_i$$
Finally take $\sup$ with the respect of $k$ of the previous inequality we deduce
$$\liminf _n \sigma_n \geq \sup _{k}\inf_{i\geq k}s_i =\liminf _is_i$$

Comment: I think I don't get the taking $\lim\inf$ part, could we explain?

Comment: Should little $s_n$ really be little $s_i$ in the definition of big $S_n$?

Comment: @CoolKid There is a sequence $k_n$ such that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sigma _n =\lim _{n} \sigma _{k_n}   $. So plugging in in our inequality $k_n$ we have $\sigma_{k_n} \geq $ RHS$(k_n)$ However the limit of the RHS exists so every subsequence converges to the same thing. Another way to think about it is if $a_n \geq b_n$ then $\liminf a_n \geq \liminf b_n$

Comment: @AOrtiz thanks for finding the typo

Comment: I wonder why it is $n-k$ instead of $n-k+1$ as there are  $n-k+1$ terms?

Comment: @CoolKid You are correct, thanks for catching this!

Comment: Quick question, why can we arbitrarily take limit of $k$ or $n$? I think $k$ is fixed.

Comment: @CoolKid you fix a $k$ and then you have that for all $n$ such that $n>k$ you get the inequality I described. Now, you take the limit in respect to $n$ since it holds for all $n$. After doing this you get something independent of $n$ and the RHS depends only on $k$. So only then, you take the supremum with the respect of $k$, i.e. $A\geq B_k$ for all $k$ then this implies that $A\geq \sup _k B_k$

Comment: That's very clear. Thank you.

Comment: But why not in respect to $i$?

Comment: @CoolKid Notice that $i$ is a dummy variable only used inside the infimum namely $\inf_{i\geq k} s_i = \inf \{ s_i| i \geq k      \}$. So the RHS depends on $k$ not on $i$. The $k$ determines the range of numbers on which we are taking the infimum.

Answer (score 0):

You can almost immediately see that

$ \min\{s_1, ...,s_n\} \le  \min\{\sigma_1, ...,\sigma_n\} \le \max\{\sigma_1, ...,\sigma_n\} \le  \max\{s_1, ...,s_n\}$

So,

$\liminf s_{n}\leq\liminf \sigma_{n} \le \limsup\sigma_{n}\leq\limsup s_{n}$